# Which is the best way to make a download controller on Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, download, controller, action

I have a system built with Spring Framework 3 and now I must implement a file download.
To execute the "donwload action" I usually get the HttpServletReponse object, set the headers and get the user outputstream from it.

It works well, but I'd like to know if there's an easier/smarter way to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds pretty good to me, the only other option would be a redirect in a hidden iframe to the file you want them to download, but i like what you have done a bit better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@ResponseBody` and return a `byte[]`

```
@RequestMapping("/getImage")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
    byte[] bytes = org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(imageFile);

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + imageFile.getName() + "\"");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: I've found that using @RepsonseBody annotation force content type to be the one of the ServletRequest.. so response.setContentType(); don't work..

Answer (score 2):

You could use the @ResponseBody or return an HttpEntity from your controller method. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody for details.

Answer (score 0):

With spring mvc you can pass `OutputStream` and `HttpEntity` as parameters, but passing the `HttpServletResponse` to a controller method is a perfectly fine approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways but they are from an architect/designer's point of view or sound software engineering principles point of view, which may or may not be easier/smarter. If you ask a designer, he might say that the controller should not be aware of the download of data (model). Some might even recommend not to use HttpServletReponse in controller and some would recommend to extend AbstractView (or choose a suitable subclass of it) so that it can be reused or flush stream in response body to separate view from controller.

There maybe other ways but my recommendation is to keep it simple and implement whatever works in the team — though I would recommend checking with designer/architect (if you have) to avoid any rework because they may have different perspective.